# Cassandra Opscenter historical view

Tags: opscenter

I recently upgraded the underlying machines of my Cassandra cluster (In AWS, from "old" to "current" generation hardware).  I *thought* I'd be able to see if this had a performance impact in Opscenter.

What I didn't consider is that as I decommissioned each node, it was being removed from the performance graphs!  This is a bummer.  Is there any hidden option to show "all collected data", even from nodes not currently in the cluster?  Is the tracking data even still there, or does it get immediately purged.

My workaround going forward will be writing down key metrics/taking screenshots otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The data from decommissioned nodes is still there, but will be removed for various granularities over time just like historical data for live nodes.  Reference: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/opsc/configure/opscChangingPerformanceDataExpiration_t.html

There is not currently a way to view that data from within the UI, but you can use the OpsCenter API directly to fetch the data: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/api/docs/metrics.html#new-get-perf-data

If this is something you need on a regular basis and/or feel like filing a feature request, go ahead and send us a message via the "Feedback" link at the top right of the UI.